# Парсер страницы, но только 403 (python)

Tags: python, requests

Пишу парсер для Яндекс.Маркета. Когда пытаюсь скачать `html` код с отзывами о магазине мне дают 403 (`forbidden`). (С помощью `requests.get(url)`). Как это исправить?

```
import requests as rqs

def get_html(link):
    return rqs.get(link).text

html = get_html("https://market.yandex.ru/shop--internet-magazin-beletazh/196744/reviews")
file = open("page.html", 'w')
file.write(html)
file.close()
```

Comment: Конкретный код приведите. Каким кодом какую ссылку пытаетесь скачать.

Comment: @CrazyElf готово

Comment: Мне в `Google Colab` пришёл ответ `<Response [200]>`. Видимо, вас Яндекс уже забанил за попытки. Правда, в самой html предлагают пройти капчу при этом.

Comment: Нет, у меня тоже 403

Comment: Яндекс банит такие запросы и подмена user-agent не помогает. Я бы предложил использовать Selenium + Chrome